# タートルグラフィックでこの図を作成したい

Tags: python

下記の図をfor, while,if構文を使って作成したいのですが、コードがイマイチわかりません。教えていただけないでしょうか？

田んぼの田の字のように2x2のグリッド線が引かれており、更に外周にある4つの辺の各中点から正三角形の線がひとつずつ引かれています。

書いてみたコードは下のようなものです。

```
import turtle def draw4squares(t, size):
    for i in range(4):
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)
```

**作成したい図**

[image]

Comment: イマイチでいいので、どんなコードを書いたか教えてもらえますか？

Comment: import turtle def draw4squares(t, size):
    for i in range(4):
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(90)
        t.forward(size)

Answer (score 2):

書き方はいくつかあると思いますが、書いていただいたコメントの修正からいきます。
以下がコメントでいただいたコードの断片だと思います。

```
def draw4squares(t, size):
    for i in range(4):
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(90)
            t.forward(size)
```

図形から「いかにも4回のループ」と気づいたところまでは良かったのですが、亀の向きの制御に手こずったんじゃないかと思います。

コードの修正点は3つです。

1. 正方形は4辺ありますから、必ず4辺forwardしないと四角が描けません。
2. 二重のforループはいずれも `i` をとっています。参照はありませんが、 `_` への代入をおすすめします。
3. 正方形を描いた後は向きに注意です。次のループに行く前に向きを変更する必要があります。

```
def draw4squares(t, size):
    # 使わない添字(i)は_で受ける
    for _ in range(4):
        # 4辺あるので4回forwardしないと四角は書けない
        for _ in range(4):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(90)
        # 1度四角を書いたら向きを変える
        t.left(90)
```

しかし図上の赤の三角形は四角形より手強そうです。四角形一つと三角形だけを見ると一筆書きができそうなので、これをいっぺんに描いてしまうことにしましょう。

```
import turtle

def draw_triangle(t, size):
    # 三角形の三辺の描画
    for rect in (-30, 120, 120):
        t.right(rect)
        t.forward(size)

    # もとの向きに戻す
    t.right(150)

def draw4pieces(t, size):
    t.pensize(3)
    t.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(4):
        # 正方形の1辺だけ先に描画してしまう。
        t.color('blue', 'green')
        t.forward(size)

        # 突き当りで赤ペンに持ち替え三角形を描画。サイズは適当です。
        t.color('red', 'green')
        draw_triangle(t, size * 1.5)

        # 最後に三角形の原点に戻ってくるので正方形の残りの辺を描画
        t.color('blue', 'green')
        for _ in range(3):
            t.right(90)
            t.forward(size)

        # 帰ってきた亀の向きは開始からちょうど
        # 90度横になったところにあるのでこれでOK!

t = turtle.Turtle()
draw4pieces(t, 100)
t.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]